# Looping AJAX request in a React component

Tags: ajax, reactjs, axios

Here's my problem. I'm trying to get some data (latitude/longitude) from a public API through an AJAX call (with Axios) in a React app.

User fills address & postcode inputs, their values are passed as parameters in the AJAX fetchCoordinates() request function, and as soon as it gets back some data, it should update latitude/longitude state with the first result's coordinates.

User can update the address and postcode inputs, and the app should consequently update coordinates state.

Here's the problematic method code :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
        fetchCoordinates(this.state.address, this.state.postcode)
            .then((data) => {
                if (typeof(data) === "object" && data.features.length) {
                    this.setState(function() {
                        return {
                            latitude: data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1],
                            longitude: data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0]
                        }
                    });
                } 
            })
    }
```

Actually, I can get the coordinates back and even render them onscreen, but as soon as I get the coordinates back, AJAX request can't stop looping, again and again...

I'm a React beginner, but that looks a suspicious behavior !

If someone had an idea, it would be kind. Thx in advance for the help.

Silvère

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.setState` should not call a function

```
 this.setState(function() { // remove the function piece here 
                        return {
                            latitude: data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1],
                            longitude: data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0]
                        }
                    })
```

Should read

```
 this.setState({
   latitude: data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1],
   longitude: data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0]
 })
```

As mentioned - you should put this code in `ComponentDidMount` or `ComponentWillMount` - not `ComponentDidUpdate`